# JS Flow: Is inheritance in Flow broken?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, flowtype

Consider a situation where you have a class B extending from class A. You create an object of type B and call a method fooA defined in A and then a method fooB defined in B.

```
class A {
  fooA () {
    console.log('fooA called')
    return this
  }
}

class B extends A {
  fooB () {
    console.log('fooB called')
    return this
  }
}

new B().fooA().fooB()
```

When run, the code logs the following as expected

```
fooA called
fooB called
```

So Javascript understands that `new B().fooA()` is an object of class B. However Flow gives me the following error message:

```
Cannot call new B().fooA().fooB because property fooB is missing in A
```

What to do? I'm interested in a solution where I do not need to change the parent class A because it is defined in an npm package. I can change B though.

Comment: I don't use flow, but I'd be inclined to think that it is behaving correctly. Considering that `A` is a super type, it has no knowledge of `B`; it only knows that `this` is an `A`, and could be any kind of subtype. So from a static type safety perspective, the type system at that point can't know that the result of `fooA` is also a `B` instance.

Comment: I wouldn't say JavaScript "understands" anything about the types. It has no built-in type safety except that which exists at runtime. At compile time, it just lets you do whatever you want.

Comment: FWIW, annotating `fooA` as `fooA (): this` fixes the issue.

Comment: As a workaround you can add a member `fooA: () => B;` to `B` class. Better solution is to provide typings for this npm package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type the `fooA` method as returning `this`, then Flow understands that any classes that extend the `A` class will also return an instance of themselves from the method:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1oDMD2H4AoCUAXNAC4AWAljMqqsBgHYQYgCmAdCBgOY4Dkm2aMDAhWAE154UNAE4tiAVxn0SFCNIC+SLUlCQYAIWgsAHsRb0xMeNXRYj+RNNoMmrDtz4Cjw0SwlSNNByisqqlJraSEj0LADu0Ab4bAKwyd74QA))

```
class A {
  fooA (): this {
    console.log('fooA called')
    return this
  }
}

class B extends A {
  fooB () {
    console.log('fooB called')
    return this
  }
}

new B().fooA().fooB() // No error
```

Since you don't want to change the `A` class: another easy way to get this working is to type the `fooA` function of `B` class to return an instance of `B`:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1oDMD2H4AoCUiKq0wGAdhBiAKYB0IGA5jgOSbYlgg0AmLeRVACdqAFwCuQstFEALAJYQiAXySqkoSDABC0agA9R1MjxjxkqdrvyFiJcpRr0mrK527U+AuyIlSZCkqoqpZYsABc0DYAvAB80NoA3GpISGTUAO4J+LTssDlW+EA))

```
class A {
  fooA () {
    console.log('fooA called')
    return this
  }
}

class B extends A {
  fooB () {
    console.log('fooB called')
    return this
  }
  fooA: () => B; // Hey Flow, this actually returns a B
}

new B().fooA().fooB() // No error!
```

Answer (score 0):

The function fooA() returns "this" which is an instance of "A". As you know, the class A has no idea that the method fooB exists. Therefore, Flow (rightfully) points out that the property fooB is missing in A.

*You* have the knowledge that in fact, this particular instance of A is also an instance of B, but Flow can't infer that. You have to tell it that the A returned by fooA() is an instance of B in this specific scenario using casting.

Changing your call to `(new B().fooA(): B).fooB()` should resolve the Flow error.

Javascript (sans Flow) doesn't care about this semantic. When you call "fooB" on the object returned by fooA() it just looks for a method called "fooB" in the object, which happens to exist, so it works, although it is more prone to breaking with refactor. Flow is helpful because it forces you stay cognizant of what types are being thrown around and gives you compile-time checks for these problems in the future.

Comment: I was just testing out their type casting on their site, and their casts still seem to require it to be provably safe. I tried that same line of code, and it still gives an error. https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAxjAhgZx2AQTAG9Uwwo44iAKAShLPLHTgDsc4YBTAOngDmNAOSVqLLDB4ATYXSbkATtwAuAV0VswKgBYBLHEwC+qExmx4wAITDcAHiu5tp+IqXJib9RsxbtOPPxwQqJUNuiSMnIKYMrqmtr6huQmZjRs3EhW9LxiBPQAXNZ0uWH0QA

Comment: It does seem to compile with `Object` though: `(new B().fooA(): Object).fooB();` https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAxjAhgZx2AQTAG9Uwwo44iAKAShLPLHTgDsc4YBTAOngDmNAOSVqLLDB4ATYXSbkATtwAuAV0VswKgBYBLHEwC+qExmx4wAITDcAHiu5tp+IqXJib9RsxbtOPPxwQqJUNuiSMnIKYMrqmtr6huQmZjRs3EhW9LxiBPQAXGAA8gBGAFbc6Cp0uWH0ANxAA

Comment: @CrazyTrain: Casting the value to `Object` lets you access any property (even if it doesn't exist). It's like a wildcard.

Comment: @FelixKling: Yeah, I figured it basically reverts to "unsafe" JS. You should post the solution you found, since it seems to describe what the OP wants in the type system.

Comment: @CrazyTrain: OP wants a solution that doesn't require to change `A`.

Comment: @FelixKling: Oh, I took that to mean that it was the OP's module and they wanted it to be broadly useful instead of making it specific to a specific subclass, but you may be right.

Comment: To be specific I can change B and the line new B().fooA().fooB() but cannot change A

Comment: "*but Flow can't infer that.*" - you should write that Flow currently *does* not infer it, it sounds like this was impossible.